# Floor and ceiling functions measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, functions

I want to show, that $$f: (\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R})) \rightarrow   (\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}))$$ $$ f(x)=\left[\frac{1}{x}\right] \forall x\ne 0 $$  $$ 0: x=0$$ is measurable. I have to consider $$f^{-1}(\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}) $$

Is this the right idea?

Comment: HINT: floor and ceiling functions are monotone piecewise continuous functions, with a countable set of discontinuities. Also you can try to write a sequence of simple measurable functions that converge point-wise to these functions.

Comment: Ok I then f is measurable, But when I don't  want to use that: If I knew f$^{-1}(\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}) $, then I could decide, wether this is measurable or not. What is $f^{-1}(\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}) $?

Comment: Please define $f$ with domain, codomain, and also insert that $x$ somehere on the L.H.S of the definition. Make sure $f$ is also defined (somehow) in zero. The "right idea" would be to show that for any $k\in\Bbb Z$ the set $f^{-1}(k)$ is measurable, which is obvious.

Comment: How would you show this. For me it is not obvious.

Comment: I added some additional information.

Comment: OK, which is the set $f^{-1}(2)$ (or more pedantly written $f^{-1}(\ \{2\}\ )$)?

Comment: This would be $ [\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: How can I go from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the floor function, if $|x| > 1$, then

$$\left\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \right\rfloor = \begin{cases}0,&x > 1\\-1, &x < -1\end{cases}$$

If $0 < |x| \leqslant 1$, then

$$\left\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \right\rfloor = \begin{cases}n, & x \in \left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n} \right]\\-(n+1), & x \in \left(\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{-1}{n+1} \right] \end{cases}$$

Thus,

$$\left\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \right\rfloor\mathbf{1}_{x \neq 0} = -\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,-1)}+\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\sum_{n= 1}^{N}n\, \mathbf{1}_{\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n} \right]}- \sum_{n= 1}^{N}(n+1)\, \mathbf{1}_{\left(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{-1}{n+1} \right]} \right),$$

which is a limit of a sequence of simple functions, and , therefore, measurable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your work:)

Comment: @Sarah: You're welcome.